# Select and rename specific multilevel column in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, rename, multi-index

```
import pandas as pd
df = {
    ('A', 'X', "k"): [1, 2, 3],
    ('A', 'Y', "k"): [4, 5, 6],
    ('B', 'X', "k"): [7, 8, 9],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns = df.columns.set_names(("level0", "level1", "level2"))
df["D"] = [1,2,3]
df
```

This is the output:

```
level0  A   A   B   D
level1  X   Y   X   
level2  k   k   k   
0       1   4   7   1
1       2   5   8   2
2       3   6   9   3
```

How to select the last column "D" and change the value of its multiindex specifically on "level2" to "E"? Ideally a way that won't require setting names for all the columns. Could not find a solution to this.
The desired state is

```
level0  A   A   B   D
level1  X   Y   X   
level2  k   k   k   E
0       1   4   7   1
1       2   5   8   2
2       3   6   9   3
```